# FirebaseSessions Swift error with Xcode 12.5.1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, react-native

I've followed the following tutorial to add Firebase to our iOS App https://rnfirebase.io/#3-ios-setup, however I keep getting the following error

> Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafeRawPointer' to expected argument type 'UnsafePointer<pb_byte_t>?' (aka 'Optional<UnsafePointer>')

This is my Pod file

````
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, min_ios_version_supported
prepare_react_native_project!

# If you are using a `react-native-flipper` your iOS build will fail when `NO_FLIPPER=1` is set.
# because `react-native-flipper` depends on (FlipperKit,...) that will be excluded
#
# To fix this you can also exclude `react-native-flipper` using a `react-native.config.js`
# ```js
# module.exports = {
#   dependencies: {
#     ...(process.env.NO_FLIPPER ? { 'react-native-flipper': { platforms: { ios: null } } } : {}),
# ```
flipper_config = ENV['NO_FLIPPER'] == "1" ? FlipperConfiguration.disabled : FlipperConfiguration.enabled

linkage = ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']
if linkage != nil
  Pod::UI.puts "Configuring Pod with #{linkage}ally linked Frameworks".green
  use_frameworks! :linkage => linkage.to_sym
end

target 'stllrmobile' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
  #$RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true 

  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # Hermes is now enabled by default. Disable by setting this flag to false.
    # Upcoming versions of React Native may rely on get_default_flags(), but
    # we make it explicit here to aid in the React Native upgrade process.
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # Enables Flipper.
    #
    # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
    # you should disable the next line.
    #:flipper_configuration => flipper_config,
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  target 'stllrmobileTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      # Set `mac_catalyst_enabled` to `true` in order to apply patches
      # necessary for Mac Catalyst builds
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false
    )
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end
end
````

And this is the code line generating the error in **SessionStartEvent.swift**

```
func encodeDecodeEvent() -> firebase_appquality_sessions_SessionEvent {
    let transportBytes = self.transportBytes()
    var proto = firebase_appquality_sessions_SessionEvent()
    var fields = firebase_appquality_sessions_SessionEvent_fields

    let bytes = (transportBytes as NSData).bytes
    var istream: pb_istream_t = pb_istream_from_buffer(bytes, transportBytes.count)

    if !pb_decode(&istream, &fields.0, &proto) {
      let errorMessage = FIRSESPBGetError(istream)
      if errorMessage.count > 0 {
        Logger.logError("Session Event failed to decode transportBytes: \(errorMessage)")
      }
    }
    return proto
  }
```

This is the line causing the error:

```
var istream: pb_istream_t = pb_istream_from_buffer(bytes, transportBytes.count)
```

> Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafeRawPointer' to expected argument type 'UnsafePointer<pb_byte_t>?' (aka 'Optional<UnsafePointer>')

Comment: No one can help you if you don’t include the code that generates the error. That said it feels like you’re doing something really wrong if you get a pointer related error like that in a tutorial.

Comment: Hello @JoakimDanielson I edited the question again with the pod file and the code causing the error, thanks a lot for your reponse

Answer (score 9):

Firebase 9.x and 10.x require at least Xcode 13.3.1. See the [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios) for additional detail.

Comment: I was skeptical this would work but it absolutely did. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I've upgraded from 10.3 to 10.6 and I'm hitting the same error as you with Unity build. Not sure how to fix it quite yet.

**Edit:**
I have modified this function a bit, given that it looks like it's not supposedly used in actual production code. With this change the code compiles and seems to be running fine:

```
/// Encodes the proto in this SessionStartEvent to Data, and then decodes the Data back into
/// the proto object and returns the decoded proto. This is used for validating encoding works
/// and should not be used in production code.
func encodeDecodeEvent() -> firebase_appquality_sessions_SessionEvent {
  let transportBytes = self.transportBytes()
  var proto = firebase_appquality_sessions_SessionEvent()
  var fields = firebase_appquality_sessions_SessionEvent_fields

  let bytes = (transportBytes as NSData).bytes
  let bytes_pt: UnsafePointer<pb_byte_t> = bytes.assumingMemoryBound(to: pb_byte_t.self)
  var istream: pb_istream_t = pb_istream_from_buffer(bytes_pt, transportBytes.count)

  if !pb_decode(&istream, &fields.0, &proto) {
    let errorMessage = FIRSESPBGetError(istream)
    if errorMessage.count > 0 {
      Logger.logError("Session Event failed to decode transportBytes: \(errorMessage)")
    }
  }
  return proto
}
```

Please note I have no idea if this cast for bytes_pt here is correct, as I'm not familiar with Swift.

Comment: I've submitted an issue to the Firebase SDK repository with proposed fix as well: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/10966

Comment: Please follow @paul-beusterien advice and upgrade the XCode version to the supported one. XCode 14.1 will be required by Apple starting April 2023 anyways to upload to AppStore, so seems like this is the only way moving forward.

In the meantime to unblock yourself you can modify the code as mentioned above to get it compile in your current setup.